# Domain Unresponsive

Tags: dns, nameservers

trying to get to the bottom of an issue.

i changed my 'main domain' with my GoDaddy account last night and, whilst I expected some database issues as I was moving sites into subdirectories, I have one that is proving an issue.

stoneinstallers.co.uk was originally the main domain.

I decided to consolidate this site into a child under fullmediamarketing.co.uk as well as others.

stoneinstallers.co.uk is now completely unresponsive is the UK yet, displays perfectly in the US.

GoDaddy have proved unhelpful as because they can see it from their Arizona office aren't willing to help because I can't see it in the UK.

All the DNS checkers are showing nameservers and records are correct as well as global propagation.

I myself used a NY proxy and it responds - just not in the UK.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean "I decided to consolidate this site into a child under fullmediamarketing.co.uk as well as others." - can you explain what exactly you changed?

Comment: Hi,

I bought the hosting and domain together under stoneinstallers.co.uk. I wanted to add extra websites to the hosting and it didn't make sense to have them under this URL as it's a client. I changed the account to be fullmediamarketing.co.uk at top level and then all the other sites (such as stoneinstallers) to be add-ons.

Comment: is it just a case of waiting for propogation? what was the TTL of the DNS record?

Comment: was set at an hour. completely unresponsive in the UK and can be seen fine in the USA. Multiple DNS and propagation checkers show that it should be fully distributed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the US and stoneinstallers.co.uk gives a 200 OK (but content is a blank white page). I used http://websitetest.com (you can have it pick multiple testing locations- I tried several in the US, Europe, and Asia) and all European and Asian locations were able to resolve the domain (Berlin, Dublin, London, Singapore, Sydney, Tokyo).
http://websitetest.com/ui/tests/55da53ac6ac6c61955000002

However, some of the US locations don't seem to be responding. There are two things I can think of that you might try:

1) Edit your DNS record and drop your TTL (time to live) down to a short time, like 30 minutes. If you have it set to a larger time (like a week), that could explain the problem. That initial TTL will have to expire of course before the new record takes effect. And even happy path (no records cached by any DNS server), DNS can take 24 - 48 hours to propagate.

2) You probably already tried this, but worth a shot. Your browser might have the page cached; can you try opening a new incognito window?